# Electron Pos Printer prints empty receipt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, electron

I am using this library [Electron Pos Printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pos-printer), and I have made a small batch of code. I have successfully connected my POS thermal printer, but when I send a command to print, it only "prints" a small amount of blank paper. Any ideas on fixing this, or maybe a recommendation for some other library?

```
let printerName = "myprinter";
let widthPage = "155";
const data = [
    {
        type: "text", // 'text' | 'barCode' | 'qrCode' | 'image' | 'table
        value: "This is sample print job",
        style: `text-align:center;font-size:16px;`,
    },
    {
        type: "qrCode",
        value: "https://github.com/fssonca",
        height: 55,
        width: 55,
        style: "margin-left:50px",
    },
];
PosPrinter.print(data, {
    preview: false, // Preview in window or print
    width: widthPage, //  width of content body
    margin: "0 0 0 0", // margin of content body
    copies: 1, // Number of copies to print
    printerName: printerName, // printerName: string, check it at webContent.getPrinters()
    timeOutPerLine: 400,
    silent: true,
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of:

```js
let widthPage = "155";
```

Try:

```js
widthPage="155px"
```